# Disable simulator in SwiftUI unit test

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swiftui, xcode12.5

I am new to SwiftUI and XCode and trying to learn it via a TDD book. So far all the tests are non-UI tests; they're just logic unit tests. Is there any way to disable the simulator when running non-UI unit tests?
It's going to run slightly faster without simulator I guess and it's slightly annoying to run an unit test with the simulator popping up every time.
I tried to edit my test scheme which only includes the unit tests not the UI tests; still it pops up the simulator every time.
I am using XCode 12.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable the simulator when running non-UI unit tests?

The way I do that is to put all my business logic code and its unit tests into a framework. Xcode tests a framework without loading the app target, so the Simulator is not involved.

Comment: For a swift beginner, please elaborate on what you mean by a 'framework'?

Comment: Well it's hard to say it more clearly. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-ADD_FRAMEWORK_TARGET for instance. If that's too much trouble or if it doesn't work well with your SwiftUI structure, don't do it (and you will just have to live with the simulator launching when you run your tests).

Comment: Sorry for picking this up again; I tried to create a framework project inside my workspace; but when running the framework code test it still loads the UI. Is it because my workspace also has a UI project?

Comment: @dragonfly02 did you manage to solve it? I'm trying to do the same as you

Comment: @DanielRamos no, seems nobody knows how to do this. Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't achieve your goal of "Disable simulator" however if your intention is to not execute any code beyond `App` then it achieves it.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let isUnitTest = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestBundlePath"] != nil
            if isUnitTest {
                Text("Unit Test")
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```